# autotools AC_CHECK_MEMBER macro not working for linux kernel struct

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, autotools

I want to define an autotools variable if a Linux kernel struct (called task_struct) has the member variable __state in it or not. This struct is defined in include/linux/sched.h. I have also tried checking other member variables (like `flags`) in that struct to no avail.

I am able to use the AC_CHECK_MEMBER macro for the struct blk_zone.capacity (as seen below) and get the correct result.

My bare bones configure.ac file to reproduce this is:

```
AC_INIT(hello-1.c)
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64"

AC_CHECK_MEMBER([struct task_struct.__state],
        [AC_DEFINE(WE_HAVE_STATE, [1], [__state member var was found])],
        [], [[#include <linux/sched.h>]])
AC_CHECK_MEMBER([struct blk_zone.capacity],
                [AC_DEFINE(HAVE_BLK_ZONE_REP_V2, [1], [report zones includes zone capacity])],
                [], [[#include <linux/blkzoned.h>]])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

My config.log file seems to be saying that there's no struct named that in the file. Any help would be much appreciated!

````
configure:2574: checking for struct task_struct.__state
configure:2574: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64 conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:14:27: error: storage size of 'ac_aggr' isn't known
 static struct task_struct ac_aggr;
                           ^~~~~~~
configure:2574: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <linux/sched.h>
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| static struct task_struct ac_aggr;
| if (ac_aggr.__state)
| return 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2574: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64 conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:14:27: error: storage size of 'ac_aggr' isn't known
 static struct task_struct ac_aggr;
                           ^~~~~~~
configure:2574: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <linux/sched.h>
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| static struct task_struct ac_aggr;
| if (sizeof ac_aggr.__state)
| return 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2574: result: no
configure:2582: checking for struct blk_zone.capacity
configure:2582: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64 conftest.c >&5
configure:2582: $? = 0
configure:2582: result: yes
configure:2742: creating ./config.status


```                           ^~~~~~~
````

Comment: You have the source of the failed program and the compile command that failed.  These appear to be consistent with the Autoconf macros presented.  Most likely, then, the `linux/sched.h` chosen by the compiler does not contain a definition of `struct task_struct`.  And you have everything needed to replicate that without going through the Autotools.

Comment: Kernel headers are not meant to be compiled for user space code such as the conftest programs.

Comment: @IanAbbott ... I think I found out first hand what you are talking about. Well I managed to get the bottom of it by copying the conftest.c code and compiling it, and running it through gcc with some -H -v flags. I DID manage to actually get this to successfully compile (thanks John) but it requires multiple includes because multiple headers started to be lost  -I/usr/src/kernels/5.17.8-300.fc36.x86_64/include -I/usr/src/kernels/5.17.8-300.fc36.x86_64/arch/x86/include  -I/usr/src/kernels/5.17.8-300.fc36.x86_64/arch/x86/include/generated/

Comment: Likewise using /lib/modules/... didn't allow some dependencies (current.h) to be found either. I guess in a situation like this it's better to just do some prodding at the command line to work out if a kernel file has changed for my given module.